# How to create a Planer Point Pattern in R using a Shapefile of point features

Tags: r, point, spatial-statistics, clustering

I have just started to learn spatial analysis of point pattern with R.

On page 20 of [this book](http://www.stats.uwo.ca/faculty/kulperger/S9934a/Computing/Spatstat-pn0y.pdf), the "Swedishpines" dataset has been used for inspection purposes. However, I want to use my own dataset intead of this data. My dataset is a group of point features having lat and and long and a text field for the point feature. Making a SUMMARY of my dataset does not result in the following details (for swedishpines data, borrowed from the book)

```
> summary(X)
Planar point pattern: 71 points
Average intensity 0.0074 points per square unit (one unit = 0.1 metres)
Window: rectangle = [0, 96] x [0, 100] units
Window area = 9600 square units
Unit of length: 0.1 metres
```

I understand that in order to follow on the example of this book, I would first need to create a Planer Point Pattern out of this Shapefile.

How can I do that?

I tried googling but nothing came up.

Comment: You might want to take a look at the `as.ppp()` function. Are your data in a data frame? A SpatialPointDataFrame? It would be easier to give a detailed answer if you provided a sample.

Comment: I checked it and my problem is solved! Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @cengel, the ppp function in spatstat package will take care of the work. Please check the following link for detailed information: http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/spatstat/docs/as.ppp